# What is the origin of the (V)BODMAS rule?

Tags: terminology

When finding out the origin of the (V)BODMAS rule, found out this from google

*"BODMAS was introduced by Achilles Reselfelt to help in solving mathematical problem involving operational signs. Whenever an operation is introduced in a sum,BODMAS rule is applicable. The BODMAS rule determines the order of operations."*

(V)BODMAS Means:

B = brackets
o = of                              (power  and square root of the terms are carried )
d = division                      (operation carried out from left- right )
m = multiplication             (operation carried out from left- right )
a = addition
s = subtraction
v (vinculum) = A horizontal line drawn over a group of terms in a mathematical expression to indicate that they are to be operated on as a single entity by the preceding or following operator.

First do bracket then powers of next do Division and multiplication then addition and subtraction of the sum. Concerned to bracket,if expression contains all the three types of brackets, the first to be disposed of are round bracket followed by curly brackets and square brackets in turn.

The question is that,in other sites(like quora),many have stated that the origin is not known.When the name "Achilles Reselfelt" is googled, am getting some kind of greek god named "Achilles".(You can try and check).

So can anyone point out to me the origin of this word and if you can, please link me to this person if he exists?

Thanks for your time.If any doubt persists please comment.

Comment: Not directly answering the question, but I found [this occurrence](https://books.google.com/books?id=gQkFAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=bodmas) of the mnemonic in a textbook from 1945: this is the earliest use of it or its variants that I could find.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for your info.Really think that the origin is unknown.Though this book may be the earliest

Comment: Even if it does not answer directly to your question, have a look at [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10981/proof-of-why-bodmas-or-bidmas-works)

Comment: @JeanMarie _Trying to "prove" a notational convention — or treating it as anything more than an agreed-upon way to efficiently communicate meaning — would represent a fundamental misunderstanding of the way mathematical notation works._ . Got this part and agree.But still maybe there was not a single person who came up with this idea but a group of people or organizations.Although its quite a surprise that the origin of the term or the agreed notation is not quite that well known.Or as the case maybe unknown :(.

Comment: Even the acronym itself is unknown in some parts of the world: this is the case in my country (France).

Comment: Why don't you tell us what the (v)bodmas rule ***is***? Do we have to click into that link to find out?

Comment: @bof Well then will edit the question now.:) But not sure if any thing would come up

Comment: Achilles Reselfelt as far as I can tell is a fiction.  Does anyone have a reliable source to show he existed and that he "invented" BODMAS?  (It appears to be one of those "facts" copied across the internet by lazy websites).

Answer (score 1):

6÷2(a+b) =  6÷2a+2b (if parentheses are 'ignored')
So, if I now give you the values of a as 1 and b as 2 ..
Then the answer would be 7!
However, by retaining the parentheses it would be  6÷(2a+2b) and give 1.
For me, the parentheses and correct use thereof, becomes rather important in describing the intent. Especially in more complex equations like I=(LR)/(1-(1+r)^-p) to calculate the installment on a bond.

Comment: This is a good answer as to why this is necessary, but it does not really answer the OP's question...

Answer (score 0):

For reference, it seems doubtful that Achilles Reselfelt existed.  The idea that he was the person who invented BODMAS circulates on the internet without a source and seems particularly popular in India.

This recent Reddit thread tried to get the bottom of this and even contacted an Indian textbook publisher who had included the reference to Reselfelt.  The result was that the publisher removed the reference!

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/178joq6/achilles_reselfelt_appears_to_be_a_fictional/